# Syntax for "hide content" or "keep but don't show" for a portion of a text on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, markdown

Is it possible on Stack Exchange sites to hide a portion of your post (answer or question)?

It would be a portion of text you have written, which you need to rewrite or alike. And you don't want to delete the text portion and also not to remove the entire answer and save it as a non-public draft. You just want to "hide" a part of an answer for now - as with the comment syntax in any programming language - to have it available in the editing environment.

Is there a markup for this in SE?

Answer (score 8):

You can use HTML comments (`<!-- ... -->`):

```
Is it possible on Stack Exchange sites to hide a portion of your post (answer or question)?

<!--
It would be a portion of text you have written, which you need to rewrite or alike. And you don't want to delete the text portion and also not to remove the entire answer and save it as a non-public draft. You just want to "hide" a part of an answer for now - as with the comment syntax in any programming language - to have it available in the editing environment.
-->

Is there a markup for this in SE?
```

Renders as:

Is it possible on Stack Exchange sites to hide a portion of your post (answer or question)?

Is there a markup for this in SE?

---

You can verify by editing the post, or [looking at the source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/6bce82e9-ce26-43de-bff1-1cd552fcd443/view-source), that the comment text is preserved.

Comment: Where's that documented? Can't find it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: @Braca well, it's not an HTML tag, it's part of the syntax. Anyway, you can find other documented uses of it in SE markdown, for example the syntax for specifying the language for syntax highlighting uses comments. It's also suggested as a way to introduce a break between two markdown elements that might otherwise be combined (two separate quote blocks, or code following a list, etc.)

Comment: @Braca It's not documented because it's not really "meant" to be used for hiding text. Technically you could just put a `<` at the beginning and a `>` at the end, because what is actually happening is that the Markdown parser is stripping anything that looks like HTML that's not on the allow list from the rendered post.